# Why the Node-RED exec node does not open the browser on Windows?

Tags: node-red

Let's say I have installed the `open` library with `npm` and I've created the `script.js` file as the following:

```js
var open = require("open");
open("https://www.google.com", "firefox");
```

If I execute it from the Windows prompt with `node C:\Users\myuser\.node-red\script.js` it opens Firefox on the page `https://www.google.com`. However, if I try to do the same using the `exec node` from Node-RED as the following:

[image]

Then nothing happens... I've checked its third and second outputs and it ends with code 0 and there are no `stderr` messages. I've also tried with chrome instead of Firefox and the result is the same, it opens while executing it from the prompt but it doesn't work when I execute it from Node-RED. What am I missing? On Linux it successfully opens any GUI software, is there any extra procedure in order to be able to open Firefox using Node-RED on a Windows machine?

---

Other commands I've observed that work fine inside the Windows prompt but don't work at all inside Node-RED with the exec node:

- `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" https://www.google.com`
- `start chrome https://www.google.com`

Comment: How are you running Node-RED on widows? If it running as a service or are you starting it manually on the command line?

Comment: Interesting... That's the issue actually, I was running it as a service using `nssm` as described on [this documentation link](https://gist.github.com/dceejay/576b4847f0a17dc066db). If I stop the service and start it manually on the command line these commands work. However, in my case I need to make it work in a service... Do you know any workaround for making it work with Node-RED running as a service?

Comment: Nope, I expect this is a deliberate design decisions by windows